# Multipart POST keeps failing in Springboot due to Content-Type header

Tags: spring-boot, postman, request-headers

I am trying to create a REST API using Spring-boot that internally talks to a java controller of some other Application. When I make an attempt to POST an image setting Content-Type as multipart/form-data using POSTMAN, I keep getting the error 500 "java.io.IOException: Missing initial multi part boundary". I went through some other blogs saying this happens because the boundary="" gets removed when we manually override the Content-Type to the header, therefore we should avoid using it. I tried the same without using the header, but then I get a 400 saying "Invalid request headers. Access denied.". Does anyone have a workaround for the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I think you can try to use Swagger in your project, not much work, you'll get APIs of your project and you can try to call your services with fine tuned default values(like Content-Type in headers).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps, used content-type as application/json

```
@RestController("/image")
public class TestControllerEx {

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity image(@RequestBody  Image image){
    System.out.println("Got image..."+image.getImage());
    return new ResponseEntity("success", HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}

public class Image {
  private byte[] image;

  public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
  }

  public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
  }
}
```

input in Postman body:

```
{"image":"dGVzdCBtZXNzYWdl"}
```